# Rules for lightning-icon static resource svgs

Tags: lightning-web-components, svg-icon, svg

We are trying to load an svg from a static resource into a lightning-icon using the source attribute. The problem we are facing is that the svg size does not match the icon size. So the icon stays empty and the visible part of the svg is rendered next to it.
[image]

By adjusting the viewBox of the svg by manipulating the DOM we are able to make it visible.
By accident we matched the svg's viewBox and found out that this made it visible.

[image]

This is what our svg markup starts with

[image]

So the questions is: what is the perfect svg ViewBox width and height to make it fit the lightning-icon component and make it scale automatically with the component's size attribute, so we can let our designers know.

Comment: I linked an answer that should solve your problem. If not, please [edit] your question to include enough code for us to replicate your problem so we can further assist you. Please don't post code as images, as this makes it inaccessible to users with accessibility software, and also makes it impossible to copy-paste so we can help diagnose issues.

Comment: Thank you. This was actually the same root cause and with tweaking things around we solved the problem. Thanks for your advice. Next time I will try to post the code

Comment: Glad I could help! This is a relatively hard-to-google question, so hopefully your question will make it easier for others to find in the future.